# my WordPress 404 Not Found error had been gone :)

Tags: database, wordpress, cpanel

I used WordPress for the first time and I changed the URL settings and this error appeared

```
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

 Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to 
 use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I tried to find **.htaccess** file but there's no such file and I tried to create one but the error still appears

I really don't know what to do .. any help, please?

-EDIT: I solved the Error 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgyaK7dpJB0&t=0s&list=LLDSGkl9MD0q2BjLLJ82nAmA&index=5 
this youtuber saved my life

Comment: 'I changed the URL settings' - You should specify what you changed otherwise it would be difficult to help you.

Comment: it was **www.zainalmansour.iq/site1/** i change it to **www.zainalmansour.iq** and my life get messy @magenta

Comment: If you're on a Mac, `.htaccess` files often never show for us in the Finder app. However, you can see them using apps such as FileZilla. Anyways, hope this guide helps you @TabarekGhassan https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/other-pages-showing-as-404-after-making-website-live-on-wordpress/

Comment: I did that already and nothing changed .. thanks @WPZA

Comment: Why don't you change it back?

Comment: nothing appears to me .. how can I change it back? @magenta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.htaccess` file. and add the code below in `.htaccess` file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You are most welcome @TabarekGhassan
You can rate my answer by clicking on up button.